# detailViewController crash on dealloc using arc due to property being released

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I am having an issue with a view controller crashing when using the back button in a navigation view controller.

In the master table view controller, I overrode prepare for segue like so:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

/*
 When a row is selected, the segue creates the detail view controller as the destination.
 Set the detail view controller's detail item to the item associated with the selected row.
 */
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"getHostedZoneSegue"]) {

    NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    GetHostedZoneViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSLog(@"setting zone ID");

    detailViewController.zoneID = [hostedZonesListID objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];

}
}
```

GetHostedViewController has a property zoneID declared:

```
@interface GetHostedZoneViewController : UIViewController 
{
    NSString *zoneID;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString *zoneID;
```

in viewDidLoad I execute this call to a method in a framework (the calls to the framework are happening in a GCD async block, and the framework does not use ARC):

```
Route53GetHostedZoneRequest *request = 
[[Route53GetHostedZoneRequest alloc] initWithHostedZoneID:self.zoneID];
```

the framework does its thing like so:
.h:

```
@interface Route53GetHostedZoneRequest : AmazonServiceRequestConfig
{
    NSString *hostedZoneID;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *hostedZoneID;
```

.m:

```
@synthesize hostedZoneID;

-(id)initWithHostedZoneID:(NSString *)theHostedZoneID
{
    if (self = [self init]) {
        hostedZoneID = theHostedZoneID;
    }
    return self;
}
```

the next call in the application is to a different method in another class in the framework using the result of the previous call:

```
Route53GetHostedZoneResponse *response = [[AmazonClientManager r53] getHostedZone:request];
```

When this is completed, both request and response are released (as expected), the weird thing is that when request is released it also releases zoneID.  Using instruments I've tracked the offending release to:

```
[hostedZoneID release];
```

In Route53GetHostedZoneRequest.m's dealloc method.

This causes a zombie when GetHostedZoneViewController is released after going back to the main controller, and crashes the app.

If I set

```
detailViewController.zoneID = @"somestring";
```

the app does not crash regardless of how many times I go back and forth.

Can anyone explain why this is crashing and maybe give me some pointers as to how to fix it?  I really don't understand why zoneID is being released by [hostedZoneID release]

Comment: Seems to me that you that you're not initializing your zone id in viewDidLoad.  Not clear because you haven't shown us what it is.

Comment: I believe it is initialized in prepareForSegue in the master view controller, this seems to be the accepted way of doing it.  @Wain nailed the issue though...  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Route53GetHostedZoneRequest` you should have:

```
- (id)initWithHostedZoneID:(NSString *)theHostedZoneID
{
    if (self = [self init]) {
        self.hostedZoneID = theHostedZoneID;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Because otherwise you aren't retaining the instance because this code isn't using ARC.

---

Your additional questions...

`NSString` instances are immutable so when you specify `copy` on the property it doesn't actually get copied it just gets retained. So the `zoneID` and `hostedZoneID` are actually the same instance.

When you use a string literal it`s a special kind of object which doesn't really get retained or released so you bypass the issue.

Comment: Yup that did it! I didn't realize that needed to be retained also, since I thought it was a copy of zoneID. I still don't really get why zoneID is released when hostedZoneID is...